# Change number with image

Tags: php, jquery, image, wordpress, numbers

I have a list of clients with his telephones numbers and i call this custom type. I want change this whole numbers with images and not html numbers.

My actual code. Show in html 555 666 777 / 333 444 555

```
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $meta1 = get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_2', true); ?>
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_3', true);
$meta1 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]*/','', $meta1);
$meta1 =
substr($meta1, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($meta1, 3, 3) . ' ' . substr($meta1, 6, 3);
echo $meta1;
if($meta != 0) {
$meta = preg_replace('/[^0-9]*/','', $meta);
$meta2 =
substr($meta, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($meta, 3, 3) . ' ' . substr($meta, 6, 3);
echo " <span style='color:#EEEEEE !important;'>|</span> ".$meta2;
} ?>
```

I wish last three numbers for example was images 7.jpg but dynamic. It's possible? If not possible only last three, all the numbers is valid too.

Example final code output:

```
555 666 <img src="7.jpg" /><img src="7.jpg" /><img src="7.jpg" />
```

Comment: really not clear what you are asking...especially last sentence. Really not clear what relation of image to text is. There is no image mentioned in code

Comment: Sorry! in the code, i get numbers, not images. I want change numbers with images. I don't want google have that info.

Comment: I updated, can you CHECK it please?

Comment: Still not clear. Indent your code properly and add some comments perhaps. What is `$meta` and `$meta1`?

Comment: $meta1 is the custom post meta. You can see it in the code. <?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $meta1 = get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_2', true); ?>

Comment: and sorry for my english :(

Comment: i created another post, you can see it here. I hope my explanation are best. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617465/change-post-meta-numbers-with-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$n1`,`$n2`, and `$n3` are the last three numbers (you need to clarify code for me to help adjust the variables appropriately, simply do:

```
echo '<img src="'.$n1.'" />';
echo '<img src="'.$n2.'" />';
echo '<img src="'.$n3.'" />';
```

(disclaimer: code is untested and is sample code-- please do not copy and paste, but rather use it as an idea. Unless, of course, you mean JavaScript side, in which case it is *completely* different)

Comment: Thanks. The numbers are a unique post_meta (555666777) and i show with this code in front.
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $meta1 = get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_2', true); ?>

Comment: I'm trying with echo ' <span class="fahrner2013'.$meta1.'2013">'; but the html output code is <span class="fahrner2013666 555 4442013"> i want only three last numbers like images... Note: fahrner2013x2013 is the css for numbers 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 with background-image

Comment: i created another post, you can see it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617465/change-post-meta-numbers-with-images