# Change post meta numbers with images

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I need get post meta value "phone" and his value is "555666777" in this post, in others, can be 456654768... or whatever

My code is this:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta($postid, 'phone', true); ?>
```

Now, i wish this numbers don't show in html like numbers, i need this numbers are images.

I have created `0.jpg 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg 5.jpg 6.jpg 7.jpg 8.jpg 9.jpg`

It's possible change the numbers of phone value with this jpgs? I don't want that google robots or anothers can this telephone numbers.

Comment: _"can be 456654768... or whatever"_: But still a perfectly legit integer, right? No dashes, `+` signs, spaces or anything?

Comment: no. only 9 numbers... i wish spaces each three numbers but is not problem.i can put that space with css or jquery later (n+3)

Comment: if it was me I would make one image sprite and setup 10 css classes to manage span tag backgrounds for the numbers.... then only one image request is made to server. Make an array of class  names and apply them according to each digit in phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way would be to isolate each digit using modulo and integer division, and produce an `img` tag out of it:

```
global $wp_query; 
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID; 
$i=intval(get_post_meta($postid, 'phone', true));
$s='';
while($i>0)
    {
    $digit=$i % 10;
    $i=(int)($i/10);
    $s="<img src='$digit.jpg' title='$digit'>$s";
    }
echo $s;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need wp_query to get current post_id

```
global $post;

$image_str = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'phone', true);

$image_array = str_split(image_str);

$image_array_with_jpg = array();

foreach($image_array as $k=>$v){

  $image_array_with_jpg[] = $v.'.jpg';
}
 print_r( $image_array_with_jpg); // array with all your post images with .jpg extension
```